# problem to show epub in release build android

Tags: react-native, epub

I try to show my epub by below code with use **epubjs-rn** package, every thing is ok in debug build and when I get release build and test, epub book not show and fix loading at begining to show,
I debug in android studio console and find same error:

```
I/ReactNativeJS: readBookEpub   id: 4868
I/ReactNativeJS: source: http://localhost:8899/4868/
E/ReactNativeJS: Empty Response
```

my code:

```
_showEpub(bookName) {
        console.log("_showEpub");


        
        const targetPath = 'http://127.0.0.1:8899/' + bookName + '.epub';




        //------------------------------------------------------show Epub 
        try {
            this.streamer.start()
                .then((origin) => {
                    console.log("Served from:", origin);
                    // this.streamer.check('http://127.0.0.1:8899/moby-dick.epub').then((t) => console.log("hiii"+t));
                    return this.streamer.get(targetPath);
                })
                .then((src) => {
                    console.log("Loading from:", src);
                    return this.setState({ urlBook: src });
                });
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log("Error: " + err);
        }
        //---------------------------------------------------


    }
```

for show book , I download book from my server by `RNBackgroundDownloader` and save , then unzip it in asset folder for read locally,
my unzip function:

```
  _unZipBook(bookName) {
        console.log("_unZipBook")

        const sourcePath = Dirs.DocumentDir + '/FaraSource/e/' + bookName + '.zip';

        const targetPath = `${Dirs.DocumentDir}/assets/${bookName}`;

        unzip(sourcePath, targetPath)
            .then((path) => {

                console.log("unZip " + bookName + "in" + targetPath);
                this._showEpub(bookName);
                // return url;
            })
    }
```

any one can help me for this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved the problem , must add one line in AndroidManifest

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        ...
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        ...>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

[more read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted/50834600#50834600)